# How to create a `name="post[name]"` using form_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

form_tag's html is :

```
 <input type="text" name="name" id="post_name">.
```

But how to make it :

```
 <input type="text" name="post[name]" id="post_name">.
```

I was doing `<%= text_field_tag :name, post[name] %>` but it throws `undefined local variable or method`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass the `name` option to the `text_field_tag`:

```
<%= text_field_tag :name, nil, name: "post[name]" %>
```

Note that the `nil` is the initial `input` value. You can alternatively have it as `params[:post].try(:name)`

Comment: Thank you. I went with first answer.